# How to get raw data from sensor(RFID)?

Tags: c++, sensors, rfid, data-stream

I need to get raw data from a set of RFID sensors. The sensor has a default application where I can see the data and they are continuously floating on the screen. Unfortunately, I can not feed the data to my program using input/output file handling in C++.

Questions:

1. Is this the process (INPUT/OUTPUT file handling) to get the raw data from sensor?
2. If not, how can I get data from sensor and feed those data into my program?

in the sensor's default application, it says I need to type some kind of "serial number" where I send the telegram.

Comment: Right now there is not enough informations to answer. The bare minimum would be the complete sensor name, reference and brand. Have you checked on the manufacturer website for documentation ?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it already. It's from SICK RFU series device.

Answer (score 1):

You normally should have a c++ API to interface with the incoming data, and this API is normally provided by the sensor vendor.

If not, then you will have to read the sensor datasheet in great detail and see the format of incoming data to hack the information coming.

Comment: Yes, I've checked the datasheet already. The sensor is reading the RFID tag, but I can not feed the data into my program. I am feeding data by manually now. :(

Comment: Are you using a serial port to connect to sensor ?

Comment: Hey Manish, I am using both serial port and ethernet.

Comment: There are c++ libraries that can help you interface with serial port and ethernet both, I at-least know of a serial library here 'https://github.com/wjwwood/serial', if you have read the datasheet then it might would have discussed the communication protocol in detail(if it is a good datasheet), use the library to implement the communication protocol to talk to your sensor.